# fade animation making my modal fail in windows 10

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, application-settings

Hey guys i have an `bootstrap modal` with `fade` CSS class.

If you like to see what am i talking about you can check it there : [`MyProject`](https://panel.technosha.com/panel/test.php)

So i'll explain it for you step by step.

First of all this page will work like this (its very simple) client will click on the `small alert modal` which you can see in the link of my project which i gave [`MyProject`](https://panel.technosha.com/panel/test.php) and after click of client its will show a modal like this picture :

[image: what is happening when click on small alert modal]

and if you can't see this modal after click on button its because of your windows setting (windows performance) if you do `right click` on `this pc (my computer)` and than if you click on properties like this :

[image: this pc properties]

and after that if you click on `Advanced system setting` on new window like this :

[image]

and again in new window if you click on `setting` in performance side you'll find the last part which i was talking about like this:

[image]

so after click on `setting` you'll be in `Performance option` window and in `Visual Effects` side you can choose 4 option and if you choose `Adjust best appearance` You are able to see this modal but if you choose `Adjust best performance` You are not able to see this modal anymore.

Picture of `Performance option` :

[image]

The thing that i want is fix it ( i meant i want to do something to stop failing modal while some client using `adjust best performance`)

Comment: If this causes the problem: don't use an animation on your modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified opacity as the root cause to the problem, as depicted in the link.

To Solve:

Remove fade class from you modal element and after that run this code:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $(this).css("opacity",1);
});
```